# Problemas com codificação de caracteres em linguagem C

Tags: c, linux, codificação-de-caracteres, iso-8859-1

Me propuseram o seguinte exercício:
"Escreva um programa C que imprima as tabelas ASCII e ISO-8859-1"

De início me pareceu simples, pois o do ASCII fiz apenas com um pequeno laço for que vai de 0 a 127 imprimindo cada um dos caracteres da tabela e funcionou perfeitamente. A ISO-8859-1 é uma extensão da tabela ASCII, então apenas ampliei o laço for para ir de 0 a 255 imprimindo cada um dos caracteres, também usei o setlocale para me certificar de que a codificação seria ISO-8859-1, segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *localidade_definida;
    unsigned char caractere;

    localidade_definida = setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.iso88591");

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        caractere = i;
        printf("%d = %c\n", i, caractere);
    }
    
    printf("A localidade definida foi %s\n", localidade_definida);
    
    return 0;
}
```

A saída disso é que ele imprime a tabela ASCII padrão e do 128 para frente ele não imprime nada :|. O ambiente de execução é o Linux Ubuntu no WSL 2, executei o comando "locale -a" e tive como resultado:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
pt_BR
pt_BR.iso88591
pt_BR.utf8
```

O que mostra que o pacote ISO-8859-1 está instalado, então deveria funcionar, como padrão, atualmente meu Linux está setado com o "pt_BR.utf8".

Então, concluindo, mesmo setando o padrão de codificação que eu quero usando o setlocale, ele não me obedece e acredito que esteja o usando o padrão que é "pt_BR.utf8", alguém sabe como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: O problema não tem a ver com o código postado (exceto o uso do `setlocale` que serve para formatação, não mudar o console), o que faltou foi configurar seu console para saída ISO-8859-1,  isso pode ser consultado em [linux.se], [ubuntu.se] ou mesmo no [su]. Ainda, dicas do OS podem ser dadas nos comentários aqui.

Comment: @JJoao me parece, pelo código, que o problema é ter UTF inválidos. De 0 a 255 todo Latin é válido (pode estar com um gliph desocupado, mas não dá erro). O que ocorre com o código acima é que ele vai acionar o começo de uma sequência de unicode indevidamente quando setar o bit maior, por isso é necessário ou um terminal de 1 byte, ou converter na saída (mas aí põe uma complexidade no código que talvez não seja desejada). Em resumo, o mais importante para o autor resolver, no meu ver, é entender a diferença entre encodings de 1 byte e de vários (e dos terminais).